# Unit partition to produce smooth function from continuous ones

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Given a positive  continuous function (except on closed set, where is zero ) on a smooth manifold how to find a smooth function under the same conditions being less (or equal) than this one continuous?

The hint was using a exhaustion of the complement of this closed set but I couldn't use it.

Comment: The complement of the closed set is an open submanifold of your given manifold. Then apply Georges's solution [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/68650). This is only a start, probably you need some more cleverness (that's probably where the exhaustion comes in) to get the function smooth on the whole manifold.